# Use blade loop variable in raw php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

My dataset describes permissions as (name, description, chapter).
Sample is:

```
'clients.edit','Editing clients','Clients'
'contracts.edit', 'Editing contracts', 'Contracts'
'works.edit', 'Editing works', 'Works'
```

I want to generate HTML with the following select via blade template:

```
<select id="sample">
    <optgroup label="Clients">
        <option value="clients.edit">Editing clients</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Contracts">
        <option value="contracts.edit">Editing contracts</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Works">
        <option value="works.edit">Editing works</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Unfortunately, pure Blade doesn't contain variable definition, so, I want to write the following Blade code:

```
<select name="permissions[]" id="permissions" class="select2" multiple="multiple" style="width: 100%;">
    @php($prevChapter = '') {{-- PHP variable visible in Blade --}}
    @foreach($permissions as $permission)
        @if($permission->chapter != $prevChapter) {{-- New chapter appeared --}}
            @if($prevChapter) {{-- It works --}}
                @php(echo "</optgroup>") {{-- Close previous chapter before new one --}}
            @endif
            <optgroup label="{{ $permission->chapter }}">
            @php($prevChapter = $permission->chapter) {{-- FATAL: Blade loop variable not visible in raw PHP --}}
        @endif
        <option value="{{ $permission->name }}">{{ $permission->description }}</option>
    @endforeach
    </optgroup> {{-- Close last chapter --}}
</select>
```

How to avoid fatal error in blade template?

Comment: Probably by adding @endphp. Give us the error's details if it doesn't help.

Comment: a `optgroup` for each option?

Comment: @Berto99 For sure - no. 1 option for 1 optgroup - just to illustrate problem shortly. In real case it would be 3-10 options per group

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for all - PHPStorm marks usage of Blade loop variable in raw PHP as severe error, but at runtime there is no problem - this code works well. I will write about PHPStorm to their support